# What are the cons of standardizing the dependent variables in a multiple regression?

Tags: regression

Is there a benefit to standardizing the variables to their Z scores before fitting a multiple regression?  Are there cons, and if so, what are they?

Comment: What method of "fitting" do you have in mind?  For some, such as ordinary least squares, standardization makes no difference and for others, such as many generalized linear models, it makes the method inapplicable.

Comment: One potential con is that the widely used fit statistic of Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) would no longer be in the same units as the original dependent variable, making interpretation of this particular fit statistic more difficult.